# Is there a way to connect to ibm mq server without the installation of client in the application server?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am developing a .net core application to connect with ibm mq.
Due to certain client restriction, we are restricted from installing the Ibm mq client.
I am using the amqmdnetstd.dll(9.3.2.0) for the connection.

Please note that the ibm mq server and application are in different systems.

Below is the code snippet i am using for the connection:

```java
    MQQueue objMQQueue;
    MQMessage objPutMQMessage;
    MQMessage objReadMQMessage;
    MQQueueManager objMQQueueManager;

    string SSLCipher = string.Empty;
    string SLLKey = string.Empty;
    string QueueManager = string.Empty;
    string QueueChannel = string.Empty;
    string ConnectionName = string.Empty;
    SSLCipher = ibmOptions.SSLCipher;
    SLLKey = ibmOptions.SLLKey;

    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SLLKey, ibmOptions.SLLKeyPassword);
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
    properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, certificate);

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Certificate object  " +                                                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(certificate));

    QueueManager = ibmOptions.QueueManager;
    QueueChannel = ibmOptions.QueueChannel;
    ConnectionName = ibmOptions.ConnectionName;
    MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = SSLCipher;           //SSL Encryption Method

    MQEnvironment.properties.Add("KeyRepository", properties);

    objMQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManager, QueueChannel, ConnectionName);


    objMQQueue = objMQQueueManager.AccessQueue("FTS.FCUBS.IN.UAT", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT +   MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
    objPutMQMessage = new MQMessage();
    //UTF-8 character encoding
    objPutMQMessage.CharacterSet = 1208;
    objPutMQMessage.WriteString("Test data");
    objPutMQMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    objPutMQMessage.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_REQUEST;
    objPutMQMessage.Report = MQC.MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID;
    objPutMQMessage.ReplyToQueueName = "FTS.FCUBS.OUT.UAT";
    objMQQueue.Put(objPutMQMessage);
    objMQQueueManager.Commit();

    if (objMQQueue.OpenStatus)
    {
     objMQQueue.Close();
    }
```

I am getting an error like dspmqver Command not found. I understand that this error is due to the fact that the application server doesn't have the client libraries installed. Is there a way to solve this without installing the client.

Comment: Can you show the exact error you are seeing, and also confirm that you are seeing this error when you run this application. If not, what command are you using when you see the error.

Comment: Yes, i am getting this error when i run the app. 

bash: dspmqver: command not found

{"ReasonCode":2538,"Reason":2538,"CompletionCode":2,"CompCode":2,"Message":"MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE","Data":{},"InnerException":null,"HelpLink":null,"Source":"amqmdnetstd","HResult":-2146232832,"StackTrace":" at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)\n at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, String Channel, String ConnName)\n at amqtesttool.Worker.DoWork() in D:\\Git\\Barclays\\IbmMq\\NewConsoleAppCore\\Worker.cs:line 57"}

Above are the errors i am getting.

Comment: I am unsure whether i am following the correct approach for the unique situation for our client. Please do guide me if i am following the wrong approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only need the one file `amqmdnetstd.dll`.  If you get an error about dspmqver it is not from the .net program, it is because you or a script you are running tried to run dspmqver.

Comment: So can i summarize that with the above code and amqmdnetstd.dll, there is no need of a client installed in the application server?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in the comments to the question, the source code you shared is very unlikely to be shelling out to call `dspmqver`.

I suspect what is happening is that you are executing your .net code which is throwing a `"2538":"MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE"`, then for additional diagnostics the script running your application, shells out to `dspmqver` to get and display the version of MQ client that your application is **not** using.

You will need to drill into server and client side logs to determine the root cause of the `2538`.